# Add remote host to known_hosts file without prompt

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, ssh-keys, known-hosts

I wrote some scripts and wish to add a remote host to my `known_hosts` file without any interaction. I can run a command like `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@10.x.x.x` which will add the remote host key to my known hosts, but it will be followed by a ssh password prompt. Any way to do this without the password prompt?

Comment: Use ssh keys for authorization instead of plain passwords.

Comment: I don't have a setup to test this at the moment, but if you pass `-o PasswordAuthentication=no` that might work? If it does, I can post this as an answer.

Comment: @DavidZ, had to use both params and when I did it worked. So `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o PasswordAuthentication=no 10.x.x.x`. Post as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @Glueon, I agree with your statement, but think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: @VenomFangs I'll still post it, but Xavier's answer of `ssh-keyscan` is a better method (and the one I would have recommended had I known about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, `ssh-keyscan` is ideal, but if for some reason you can't do that: You can disable password authentication by either setting the option

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

in a configuration file (e.g. `.ssh/config`), or passing the option `-o PasswordAuthentication` on the command line, and thus prevent ssh from asking you for a password. Needless to say, the server sees this as a failed login attempt, unless you have another authentication method configured that *does* let you log in.

As you've already noted, changing the value of the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option from `ask`, the default, to `no` (or `yes` if you want better security) is necessary to avoid the prompt about whether you want to add the host key to `.ssh/known_hosts`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `ssh-keyscan 10.x.x.x >> /path/to/known_hosts/file` (use -H for better security, depends on the context).